# RPC Programming Language C

Tags: c, rpc

I need some help at RPC Programming. I really want understand how works the RPCGEN and the MAKEFILE structure. I would like a recommendation of a good introductory book at RPC. I found some examples but I dont know how to compile/integrate the files. More specifically i have a Client source code (one file), a Server source code (one file) and a "makefile source code". All i want is put this example to work.

Comment: Have you tried.... reading the code? Or the Makefile? Have you searched Google for relevant information?

Comment: yes, and when I run rpcgen file.x command, appears a error preprocessing failed with error 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few resources you might find helpful.

1. [Tutorial of RPC programming](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html)
2. [How RPC works -pdf link](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/23.rpc/paper.pdf)